# Smooth item extrusion becomes faceted

Tags: topology, extrude, smooth

Sometimes while working a soft shaded item such as an imported Daz Studio figure, any new extrusion I make (for geografts) looks faceted, though the original area is still smooth. How do I make those new polys match the original?

Comment: Without seeing any images of what you're talking about it's impossible to say. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post